# 2d random walk in python - drawing hypotenuse from distribution

Tags: python, random, trigonometry, hypotenuse

I'm writing a simple 2d brownian motion simulator in Python. It's obviously easy to draw values for x displacement and y displacement from a distribution, but I have to set it up so that the 2d displacement (ie hypotenuse) is drawn from a distribution, and then translate this to new x and y coordinates. This is probably trivial and I'm just too far removed from trigonometry to remember how to do it correctly. Am I going to need to generate a value for the hypotenuse and then translate it into x and y displacements with sin and cos? (How do you do this correctly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done by using **polar coordinates** `(r, theta)` for your distributions (where `r` is your "hypotenuse")), and then converting the result to `(x, y)`, using `x = r cos(theta)` and `y = r sin(theta)`.  That is, select `r` from whatever distribution you like, and then select a `theta`, usually from a flat, 0 to 360 deg, distribution, and then convert these values to `x` and `y`.

Going the other way around (i.e., constructing correlated (x, y) distributions that gave a direction independent hypotenuse) would be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hypotenuse in the form of a line segment, then you have two points. From two points in the form `P0 = (x0, y0)` `P1 = (x1, y1)` you can get the x and y displacements by subtracting `x0` from `x1` and `y0` from `y1`.

If your hypotenuse is actually a vector in a polar coordinate plane, then yes, you'll have to take the `sin` of the angle and multiply it by the magnitude of the vector to get the y displacement and likewise with `cos` for the x displacement.